# Comment flags incorrectly rejected. How to resolve?

Tags: support, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

A question poster ended up posting two comments below their question with lots of details that should have been put in their question. I posted a comment suggesting the OP put the information into their question which they ended up doing a few minutes later. The OP copied their comments into the question verbatim plus added a bit more info.

So I deleted my comment and then flagged the OP's two comments as no longer needed. But  both of my flags were rejected for some reason.

I'm not sure why my flags were rejected since the info is now in the question where it belongs and the OP's comments are unnecessary and redundant.

Is there an appropriate follow-up for a situation like this that I can take?

Comment: My advice is in the future raise a custom flag saying they have since edited the info into the question/answer since the mod probably doesn't look at the post (just a guess) well handling comment flags

Comment: In general, the only information we get on a "No longer needed" flag is the text of the comment (in isolation without the context of any of the other comments on the post). For this reason, on less clear cut cases, it's super helpful to explain (in a mod flag) why an *apparently relevant* comment should be deleted (_e.g._ because that relevant information has been moved into the question).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My bad. When I reviewed the comment flags, it wasn’t clear to me that the OP had already incorporated the comments into their question. I’ve deleted the comments now. Thanks for the heads-up.

Update: As far as the *“Is there an appropriate follow-up for a situation like this that I can take?”* part of the question, it seems the answer for that is what Ethan’s comment advises: *“raise a custom flag saying they have since edited the info into the question/answer”*.

Otherwise, without that — as Henry’s comment notes — all that the moderator team sees directly in the flag-handling mod UI is the “the text of the comment (in isolation without the context of any of the other comments on the post)”.

So to get more context, one thing that any mods handling the flag should do is to check for any edits the OP made to a post after the flags were raised. But it’s risky to assume that’s always going to happen — and so to ensure the mods see the full context, it’s safer to raise a custom flag explicitly stating *“the OP edited this comment into the question”* or some such.